# vbscript runtime error:invalid procedure call or argument

Tags: c#, asp-classic, com

I have an asp page, from which I have to call a .net dll which is registered by regasm. It is working fine. Now my requirement is passing an ADODB.Recordset to the .net dll from asp page. like:

```
Set class1=CreateObject("namespace1.class1")
Result=class1.function1(str,rsSet).
```

and in .net  function:

```
Public object[] function1(string value,ADODB.Recordset rsSet)
```

But at the time of calling the function from asp it gives the error:

```
vbscript runtime error:invalid procedure call or argument
```

Any clue will be appreciated.

Comment: is there any marshalling required for this job?

Comment: Add **Server** to `Set class1=Server.CreateObject("namespace1.class1")`